# VBSCRIPT SAVEAS

Tags: vbscript, save-as

I have the following:

```
set wshshell=createobject("wscript.shell")
wshshell.run """C:\ReportName.pdf"""
```

This opens the named PDF.  What code do I need to save that opened file as, like a SaveAs.. saving it as the same filename?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `WshShell.SendKeys` to simulate the SaveAs on the active window.

Comment: Hi.  I now have WshShell.SendKeys "{SHIFT}^{CTRL}+S" and the error says "invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: Yea, you might have to wait for few seconds (like `wscript.sleep 1000`) so that the file is opened and how about `wshshell.SendKeys "%{F}{A}"`

Comment: thanks.  the wshshell.SendKeys "%{F}{A}" works, but it brings up the SAVE dialog box.  How can i simulate clicking SAVE from the dialogue box?

Comment: Try using filesystemobject for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code

```
set wshshell=createobject("wscript.shell")
wshshell.run """C:\ReportName.pdf"""
wscript.sleep 2000 'sleep for 2 seconds to ensure file is open
wshshell.SendKeys "%{F}{A}" 'simulate ALT+F+A to open SaveAs dialog
wscript.sleep 5000 ' sleep for 5 seconds so that the save as dialog is open
wshshell.SendKeys "+{TAB}{ENTER}" 'simulate Shit+Tab so that the tab is moved backed to Choose a diff folder option
wscript.sleep 2000
wshshell.SendKeys "C:\NewFile.PDF{ENTER}"
wscript.sleep 3000
wshshell.SendKeys "%{F}{X}"
```

Comment: thanks.  how about closing the original PDF file?  I have: wshshell.SendKeys "^{CTRL}+{W}" but its not working

Comment: got it.  one thing i have noticed is that while the code is running, if there is a reminder/dialog box that comes up when i have a google calendar event come up, that the VBS code is stopped/terminated.  how can i prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to copy the file or move/rename the file. If so, use [`FileSystemObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51(v=vs.84).aspx):

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Call fso.CopyFile("C:\ReportName.pdf", "C:\NewReport.pdf")
' or
Call fso.MoveFile("C:\ReportName.pdf", "C:\NewReport.pdf")
```